# QBFC: Can I call multiple concurrent calls to quickbooks through one session?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

I am currently creating a new quickbooks session for every unique "thread" coming into my SDK app. In that session, I do some quickbooks stuff.

It seems to be working well, allowing multiple things to happen at the same time. The problem I have, is that the session sometimes takes a while to "open".

If I create a single "global" session, can I call that concurrently form my individual threads? Will quickbooks allow me to make concurrent sdk calls through the same session?

I would like to get some insight into this before I go and change my currently working code...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make multiple calls under one session open. They have to be sequential. They cannot run in parallel. So you can only have one connection open to QB at a time.

Comment: Ok, see thats what I am after. I want to make a single connection, but then make concurrent (parrallel) calls to QB within that session. So, cant be done then. Thanks.